# What genre of beings would Gods, Angels, Demons and Devils classify under?

Tags: mythical-creatures, fantasy-races

So how elves, fairies, and dragons are all magical creatures

Gods, Devils, Angels and Demons

They are all....what?

Comment: Divine creatures.

Comment:  thank you! I can't believe Divine completely slipped my mind

Comment: Probably divine "entities" would be more appropriate.

Comment: Looks more like a question for writing stack.

Comment: Or English.StackExchange...

Comment: They are often classed as Celestials

Comment: By the way how are demons and devils classified as divine creatures

Comment: @Persivefire - traditionally (in Christian settings - see Paradise Lost) devils are fallen angels and so not fundamentally different from the non-fallen angels.  Of course demons of various sorts appear in all sorts of other cultural settings.

Comment: for us it is the other way round, gods are glorified demons

Comment: i am hindu by the way

Answer (score 6):

I would assert that there is not a single correct answer to this question.

If you are writing a religious story with

> Gods, Devils, Angels and Demons

then they are considered heavenly beings and hellish creatures.

If you are writing a fantasy story with

> Elves, fairies, dragons, Gods, Devils, Angels and Demons

then they are all magical beings, of varying sub-classes.

What is more, if you are in a room full of skeptical atheists, discussing

> Gods, Devils, Angels and Demons

then they will tend to be referred to as delusions, or "mythical-creatures" (like the tag you appended to your question).

If you are in a church, surrounded by believers, talking about

> Gods, Devils, Angels and Demons

the terms bandied about would be the same as in the religious fiction example.

Since this is a Stack Exchange: Worldbuilding context...

I assume, whatever genre you intend, in-world these things will be real, and they will probably be referred to as in the religious fiction or church contexts.

Or, if there's controversy regarding their existence in-world, see the other alternatives, and expect characters to disagree on how to categorize them.

---

As a catch-all term, **the supernatural** will tend to evoke

> Gods, Devils, Angels and Demons [and ghosts and poltergeists]

(but it will be less evocative of elves, dragons, fairies, etc)

Comment: Whoa yes awesome! This is exactly the kind of break down I was looking for. I'm trying to classify them as a singular "race" per say, so instead of grouping them together I want to Generalise them? I'm not sure if thats the right word. an example I can think of is how there are different kinds of snakes, such as cobras, pythons, anacondas and such, but to generalise them its just "Snakes" or "Different Snakes" even though they're not all the same, they're all still snakes. I want to be able to single them out.

Comment: @nuckinfutz Added a catch-all term

Comment: A seemingly reasonable answer, ultimately of the "call em whatever you want" sort. In other words, not really useful. Rather than assert an answer based on genre, perhaps looking at the meanings & realities behind the words themselves would suggest a better understanding.

Comment: Sometimes the correct answer is "It depends on the context; here are different contexts to illustrate." @elemtilas  Feel free to post a better answer.

Comment: @Jedediah -- sometimes, yes, answers are context dependent. This isn't one of them, though.

Comment: @elemtilas Please post a better answer, to illustrate what you mean.  I'll be happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 5):

I realise some of those might be a bit more specific to one side or the other (good vs evil), but do any of those work?

- Celestial
- Heavenly
- Empyrean
- Angelic
- Chthonic (great word)
- Devilish
- Demonic
- Hellish
- Infernal

Comment: If you're going with Chthonic then you need Diabolical

Answer (score 3):

These are some ideas of classifications:

- **Celestials:** it refers to any creature (good or evil) which comes from another place, usually from the skies (literally [planets] or metaphorically [heavens] speaking).
- **Angelical:** from angels.
- **Heavenly:** creatures (not necessarily angels) from the heavens.
- **Devilish:** from the devil.
- **Hellish:** creatures from the hell, not necessarily demons. They may be souls or another stuff from there.
- **Infernal:** any creature which inhabits the hell.
- **Sacred:** creatures considered sacred by some religion.
- **Holy:** sacred creatures with "holy" power.
- **Unholy:** profane or unholy creatures.
- **Undead:** creatures that *were* dead, but now they got reanimated.
- **Divine:** creatures with divine power. Divine doesn't mean sacred or good, it only means "godlike" power.
- **Upper:** creatures from upper planes (like heaven or another place in your fantasy world).
- **Lower:** creatures from lower planes (like hell or another place in your fantasy world).
- **Median:** creatures from median planes (like our world or another place in your fantasy world).
- **Extraplanars:** creatures from other planes of existence.
- **Extradimensionals:** creatures from other dimensions.
- **Extraplanetary:** creatures from other planets.
- **Humanoids:** creatures with human-like shape and appearance.
- **Commoners:** humans.
- **Fantastic:** fantasy creatures.
- **Fairy:** fairy-like creatures, with mystic nature.
- **Mythical:** fantasy creatures but even rarer in fantasy worlds, usually mystic and powerful or difficult to find.
- **Legendary:** more "mythic" than mythical creatures itself, only found in legends or tales.
- **(Un)Sentient / (Un)Speakable:** creatures (not) able to think and usually talk.
- **Salvage / Wild:** animal creatures, wild.
- **Primordial:** creatures of primordial existence, formed before everything, even time or space itself, outside the realm of physic or before the existence of physic (usually **primordial gods** *make* physic).
- **Elemental:** creatures of elemental existence (fire, water, earth, air, etc).
- **Aquatic:** creatures that live underwater or are water elementals / from water planes.
- **Underground:** creatures that live underground or are earth elementals / from earth planes.
- **Aerial:** creatures that live on air itself or are air elementals / from air planes.
- **Incendiary:**  fire elementals / from fire planes.
- **Timeless:** creatures that aren't affected for time itself, are immortal or related to time itself.
- **(Im)mortals:** creatures than can (not) be killed.
- **Day:** creatures of light, day and good.
- **Night:** creatures of darkness, night and evil.
- **Twilight:** evil creatures of darkness or creatures that don't belong either day or night.

Comment: `Celestials` - it's actually related to the skies. This could involve the literal skies (the moon and stars are celestial bodies, for example) or the more metaphorical with heaven (synonym to heavenly). Unless evil creatures come from "above" (literally or not), they are unlikely to be celestial. `Primordial` doesn't really imply outside the realm of physics. It's a term roughly equivalent to "earliest". "Primordial soup" is the name for the environment that gave start to life on Earth. `inmortals` -> "I**m**mortals"

Comment: @vlaz you have right in that. I now that `primordial` isn't outside the realm of physics exactly, but as you said, they are "earliest", usually formed before physic itself (like primordial gods which *made* the physic).

Answer (score 3):

Along with the other excellent answers, I'd suggest *spiritual* beings.

By using this term, you'll evoke a combination of Merriam-Webster [definition 5](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spiritual):

> of or relating to supernatural beings or phenomena.

And definition 2b:

> ecclesiastical rather than lay or temporal.

This should give readers the impression of a supernatural entity with a religious focus.

In particular, compare Ephesians 6:12 from the Christian Bible, New International Version:

> For our struggle is **not against flesh and blood**, but against the rulers, against the authorities, against the powers of this dark world and against the **spiritual forces** of evil in the heavenly realms.

Comment: This answer is accurate.  "Gods", angels, demons and "devils" are all spirits.    Angel is a job title, not the name of a class of beings.  'Angel' means 'messenger'.  So an 'angel' is a spirit who is a messenger of God, the way a 'police officer' is a man who works in law enforcement.  https://www.biblestudytools.com/dictionary/angel/

Comment: "By nature they were spiritual entities, and thus not subject to the limitations of human flesh." https://www.biblestudytools.com/dictionary/angel/

Comment: @TheLeopard - Some police officers are women who work in law enforcement too. :) But thanks. I was surprised that none of the other comprehensive answers had mentioned "spirits" or "spiritual."

Answer (score 1):

- (good/bad) celestials.
- Divine creatures (thanks Willk)
- higher beings
- (Un)Holy creatures